# using m2e and getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpProvider

Tags: eclipse, installation, m2e, sonatype

I use the m2e plugin in eclipse luna.

When i run with the goal clean install is an error thrown.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    deconFm_Version5
    decon_fm_version5
    war
    0.0.2
    decon_fm_version5 Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>

    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <hibernate.core>3.3.2.GA</hibernate.core>
    <hibernate.annotations>3.4.0.GA</hibernate.annotations>
    <javax.persistence>1.0</javax.persistence>
    <javassist.version>3.12.1.GA</javassist.version>
    <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql.version>

    <jersey.version>1.13</jersey.version>

    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>

    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>

    <org.slf4j.version>1.7.2</org.slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>

    <commons.collections.version>3.2.1</commons.collections.version>
```

2.3</commons.lang.version> -->

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Komponenten -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Datenbank Komponenten -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.core}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.annotations}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.persistence}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>${javassist.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Komponenten -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Components -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey - Spring Integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging Komponenten -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/javac</executable>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This the stack trace.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building decon_fm_version5 Maven Webapp 0.0.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ decon_fm_version5 ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Projects\Java\decon_fm_version5\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ decon_fm_version5 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 35 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ decon_fm_version5 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ decon_fm_version5 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Projects\Java\decon_fm_version5\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ decon_fm_version5 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\Projects\Java\decon_fm_version5\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ decon_fm_version5 ---
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/
constituent[1]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-core-3.0.4.jar
constituent[2]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-model-3.0.4.jar
constituent[3]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-settings-3.0.4.jar
constituent[4]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-settings-builder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[5]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.4.jar
constituent[6]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-artifact-3.0.4.jar
constituent[7]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-plugin-api-3.0.4.jar
constituent[8]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-model-builder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[9]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-aether-provider-3.0.4.jar
constituent[10]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/aether-api-1.13.1.jar
constituent[11]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
constituent[12]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
constituent[13]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
constituent[14]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
constituent[15]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[16]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[17]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[18]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/commons-cli-1.2.jar
constituent[19]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/maven-compat-3.0.4.jar
constituent[20]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/wagon-provider-api-2.2.jar
constituent[21]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-plexus-shim-2.3.0.jar
constituent[22]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[23]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-bean-reflect-2.3.0.jar
constituent[24]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-bean-locators-2.3.0.jar
constituent[25]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-bean-binders-2.3.0.jar
constituent[26]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-bean-scanners-2.3.0.jar
constituent[27]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-bean-converters-2.3.0.jar
constituent[28]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-plexus-metadata-2.3.0.jar
constituent[29]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-plexus-converters-2.3.0.jar
constituent[30]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-plexus-locators-2.3.0.jar
constituent[31]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-plexus-binders-2.3.0.jar
constituent[32]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-bean-inject-2.3.0.jar
constituent[33]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-plexus-scanners-2.3.0.jar
constituent[34]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guice-plexus-lifecycles-2.3.0.jar
constituent[35]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
constituent[36]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/guava-11.0.2.jar
constituent[37]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
constituent[38]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/aether-spi-1.13.1.jar
constituent[39]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/aether-impl-1.13.1.jar
constituent[40]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/aether-connector-asynchttpclient-1.13.1.jar
constituent[41]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/wagon-ahc-1.2.1.jar
constituent[42]: file:/D:/Eclipse_201502_Luna/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/533/0/.cp/jars/wagon-file-2.2.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpProvider
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:106)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:346)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:453)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:240)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:308)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpProvider
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 35 more
```

What is the problem? Google did not help me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following dependency to my pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
    <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.32</version>
 </dependency>
```

I am still investigating which dependency depends on this and why this happened now.